# @Cacheable [Spring MVC] not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations, spring-cache

My spring project has a jar packaging. I am using Spring 4.3.2
In my resources folder. I have an xml based config file : abc-servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
         xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
         xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">

<cache:annotation-driven />

<context:component-scan base-package="sayak.auth,
                        sayak.member"/>

<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager">
    <property name="caches">
        <set>
            <bean class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean"
                    p:name="memberInLastMonth"/>
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I am using @Cacheable on a dao method like below and also annotated the class with @Component :

```
@Cacheable(value="memberInLastMonth" , key="#authenticationId")
public List<AuthenticationAuditTrail> findByAuthenticationId(long authenticationId) {
//DB call to fetch data
}
```

The result from this method is not getting cached when invoked on same authenticationId , I have used a simple assert to check it and not getting the desired result. Any lead will be helpful.

The test method for this :

```
@Test
public void testMemberInLastMonth() {
Member member=getMember();
List<AuthenticationAuditTrail> records = getDAO()
    .findByAuthenticationId(member.getAuthentication().getId(),
        DateUtil.getPastMonth(1));
List<AuthenticationAuditTrail> cachedRecords = getDAO()
    .findByAuthenticationId(member.getAuthentication().getId(),
        DateUtil.getPastMonth(1));

for(int i=0;i<records.size();i++){
  AssertUtil.assertTrue(records.get(0) == cachedRecords.get(0));
}
```

}

Comment: How are you invoking the method in DAO, do you have a test case that you can post here for reference.

Comment: Are you talking about "findByAuthenticationId" method invocation or the logic inside the method ?

Comment: Explore `@CachedResult.`

Comment: @ShanuGupta Can you share some links ?

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj 

"findByAuthenticationId" is invoked from another class , there I am actually looping through the list elements and doing a simple asertEquals

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj , Have updated the question with Test method as requested

Comment: findByAuthenticationId takes 2 arguments (id, date) are you sure you are testing the right method. And never use == for comparing object, use .equals()